# Uninitialized string offset

Tags: php

```
protected static function generateString ($length = 50, $Password){
        $characters = $Password;
        $string = '';

        for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
            $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))]; // Error Line
        }
        echo $string;
    }
```

Hello. I am building an authentication class, and the function above is giving me some  grief, I keep getting presented with the error message:

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 16

The echo is there for testing purposes.

I am calling my function using:

```
 public static function Compile($Password, $Length){
        self::generateString($Length,$Password);
    }

Auth::Compile('testi ngpassword', 10);
```

When I run my script, sometimes it generates with no error message; but when running multiple times (3- 7) I get presented with the message as specified above? and sometimes this notice shows over two lines?

So why is it the error message is getting generated randomly when repeatedly running? when the arguments specified is not changing?

Comment: strings are zero based, their length starts with 1... so the last character will give wrong offset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider this line:

```
strlen($characters)
```

if the string length is 16 and you make a random number select between 0 and 16 you are giving it the option to select the index after last, which is nothing. You need to make it

```
strlen($characters) - 1
```

Since the index actually begins at 0;

Comment: `[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters) -1)];` is still presenting with the error messages

Comment: when you print_r $characters it is producing something, right? The above statement would also happen if characters had a length of zero.

Comment: Please  dis-regard that last comment, I was editing the wrong snippet, not the code as I exampled. It has worked, so for future reference, `strlen` appends +1 to the length when called? hence telling the index to start at -1?

Comment: no, strlen is a literal count of the string contents. But calling a string offset the way you are - string[0] would select the first character. As youn mentioned, the zero based strings when coupled with a length that starts at 1 would mean that a 16 character string being accessed like string[16] would be attempting to locate a character at the 17th index since the first character starts at 0... that sounds confusing but it may make more sense to think of php reading brackets [] like an array.